# How to compare rows in Python to see difference in value?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to essentially get a list of all the items where the total does not match the sum of the weekly items.

[Click here for image of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emBo9.png)

The column headers of the csv are Name, Type, EMPID, Year, Period, UniqueID, and Value.
In the ideal scenario, the logic in the script should return instances where -- when the its the same **EmpID** and the same **year** and the same **uniqueID** and the same **Name** and the same **Type** -- ** then Total Should NOT equal to (week 1 + week 2 + week 3 + week 4)**

If the total equals the sum of the weekly items, we dont want that.

I'm getting confused when i have to diff against the total values and the sum of the weekly rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide a easy to copy example of the dataframe next time.

```
#df = your_dataframe.copy()

df_totals = df[df["Period"]=="Total"]
df_without_totals = df[df["Period"]!="Total"]

df_without_totals = df_without_totals.groupby(["Name", "Type", "EmpID", "Year", "uniqueID"])["Value"].sum().reset_index().rename(columns={"Value":"Summed_Value"})

df_compare = df_totals.reset_index().merge(df_without_totals, on=["Name", "Type", "EmpID", "Year", "uniqueID"], how="left").set_index("index")

df_compare[df_compare["Value"] != df_compare["Summed_Value"]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to select the weeks instead of using df_without_totals = df[df["Period"]!="Total"]? What if i had week 5, and only wanted the first 4?

Comment: Yes, you could do something like: df_without_totals = df[df["Period"] in ["week1","week2","week3","week4"]]

Comment: I get the following error when using df_without_totals = df[df["Period"] in ["week1","week2","week3","week4"]] : 

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: You are right, my bad, try: df[df["Period"].map(lambda x: x in ["week1","week2","week3","week4"])]

Comment: Thank you for this! It was really helpful!

I had one additional question. Is there any code I can write, which will make the logic run only when all Week1, week2, week3 AND week4 are present?

For example, for an item if week 3 doesn't exist, i want to leave that out of my result, and move on to the next item.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest that you pivot by ID and Period, and iteratively compare the sum of weeks to Total. This is what the following code does, and if the sum of Weeks is not equal to Total, it prints the unique ID. Please let me know if this helps.

Say that your dataset's name is df:

```
for ID, Period in df.groupby('UniqueID'):
    By_ID = Period.groupby('Period').sum()
    Week_Sum = sum(By_ID['Value'])
    Total = By_ID['Value'][0]
    if Week_Sum - Total != Total:
        print(ID)
```

The answer it gives on the data you posted is IDs 2 and 3.